# Can I convert .SVG animationfile to ,Json?

Tags: json, svg, lottie

I'm trying to use Lottie Library in jetpack compose
For animating image, I made animating svg file.
But in https://lottiefiles.com/svg-to-lottie, the animating svg file converted to static json file which I didn't intent.
How could I convert animating svg file to animating json file?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have use Adobe AE and convert your animation with lottiefiles or bodymovin extesions to .json.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Okey,
1- first open your .svg file with illustrator.
2- then you'll need to save the file as .ai (adobe illustrator).
3- after that you can open the .ai file with adobe after effects.
4- then with lottiefiles extension you will be able to convert and save the file as json.
pretty simple right? this method only works if your svg is not animated.
to convert an animated svg, so far and obviously as far as I know you'll need redraw your animation in illustrator and animate it in after effects.
this link will probably be of use.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPha_s7W-0M

Comment: You can simply edit your other answer instead of adding to a new one...